# How to register zuul to eureka using Google Cloud Run?

Tags: devops, gcloud

I have a typical architechture using Eureka-Zuul-MicroServicesA.

This is working fine but when I try to deploy the micro services to Google Cloud Run the Server Zuul couldn't be registered with eureka because it doesn't find eureka.

I will attached the configuration about eureka server:

[image]

Now I show the configuration using Zuul Server

[image]

Does anyone have a guide on how to deploy eureka and zuul in Google cloud?